# Generics question. Do I need reflection to answer this?

Tags: vb.net, generics, reflection

```
Public Class B

End Class


Public Class D

    Inherits B

End Class

Public Class SomeClass


    Public Shared Sub SomeFunction2(Of TGeneric As B)()

        'Is there a way that I can tell whether the the Type used
        'as TGeneric is of type "B" or "D" without having 
        'an instance of a class also passed in?
        'Reflection? How?

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        SomeClass.SomeFunction2(Of D)()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "is of type B or D".

If you only want to differentiate between someone actually calling `SomeFunction2(Of B)` and `SomeFunction2(Of AnyTypeThatInheritsFromB)`, then you can just do:

```
If GetType(B) Is GetType(TGeneric) Then
    ... they passed in B
Else
    ... they passed in a subclass
End If
```

But this seems like a bit of a code smell. Generics are intended for you *not to care* what the actual type is. What's the reason you need to know?